# sonar-maven-plugin fails with GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, sonar-maven-plugin

We scan projects with the sonar-maven-plugin and struggle over this error in the respective Jenkins stage

```
...
14:46:19 [INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor
14:46:19 [WARNING] You are not using the latest JaCoCo binary format version, please consider upgrading to latest JaCoCo version.
14:46:19 [INFO] Analysing D:\jenkins\workspace\example-master-TD7G6HW7YEVZGI5SB6KAKUAC2HNRPENMLFLUMZSUIJN4VX6DGSKQ\..\target\jacoco.exec
14:47:06 Exception in thread "xxxx" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
14:47:06    at java.util.ArrayList.iterator(ArrayList.java:840)
14:47:06    at com.persistit.TimelyResource.prune(TimelyResource.java:303)
14:47:06    at com.persistit.Persistit.pruneTimelyResources(Persistit.java:2499)
14:47:06    at com.persistit.Persistit.cleanup(Persistit.java:1531)
14:47:06    at com.persistit.CleanupManager.poll(CleanupManager.java:157)
14:47:06    at com.persistit.CleanupManager.runTask(CleanupManager.java:88)
14:47:06    at com.persistit.IOTaskRunnable.run(IOTaskRunnable.java:144)
14:47:06    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved when the sonar.jacoco.reportPath property is added to the pom.xml (line 6):

```
<properties>
   <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   <!-- this is defined in spring-core-env and fits for multi module project. Scanner fails for single module projects! -->
   <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
</properties>
```

This can be found reading trough comments of https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JaCoCo+Plugin